# How can I retrieve the record in the table using their ID.?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-modal

I'm having trouble in retrieving records. I have a table and it contains records. I want to view the details of that record using the view button. But the problem is when I try to view the record all of the records is showing same details even though they are different in the database. I'm retriving the records using their ids. Here are my code

```
<table class="table">
                    <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Family Number</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Chief of Complaints</th>
                    <th>Diagnosis</th>
                    <th>Medication Treatment</th>
                    <th>Time Added</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php do{ ?>
                        <tr>
                                <td class="patient_id"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['family_number']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Age'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['chief_complaints']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['diagnosis']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['medication_treatment']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['added_at']; ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col-2">
                                    
                                    <!-- <a href="view_medicalrecord.php?id=<?php //echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">view</a> -->
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary view_btn mb-2">view</a>
                                    <!-- <div class="dropdown">
                                     <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                       Dropdown button
                                     </button>
                                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                       <li><a class="dropdown-item view_btn" href="#">View</a></li>
                                       <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a></li>
                                     </ul>
                                     </div>
                                    
                                    </div> -->
                                    
                                     
                                </td> 
                          </tr>
                    <?php }while($row = $medical_itr->fetch_assoc()); ?>
                    </tbody>
```

ANd this is my js code for retrieving the data using their id

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.view_btn').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var p_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.patient_id').text();
      // console.log(p_id);

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Modals/viewHistory/view_medical_itr.php",
        data: {
              'checking_viewbtn': true,
              'patient_id': p_id,
        },
        success: function (response){
          // console.log(response);
          $('.patient_viewing').html(response);
          $('#medical_itr').modal('show');

        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

And this is my php code for retriving data in the database

```
include_once("connections/connections.php");

$con = connection();

if(isset($_POST['checking_viewbtn'])){

$p_id = $_POST['patient_id'];


$sql = "SELECT * FROM medical_itr WHERE id = '$p_id'";

$medical_itr = $con->query($sql) or die ($con->error);

$row = $medical_itr->fetch_assoc();

}
```

This is sample pic
[As you can see in the picture in the bottom left the id is 31 same as the url, but the view button I'm trying access the id in the table is 21.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rv0t.png)

Comment: This `href="#"` is why the id in the lower left is showing id 31. Using "#" as an href means to point to the url of the current page.

Comment: Can you try ( var p_id = e.target.closest('tr').find('.patient_id').text();

Comment: the modal stop working when I tried that. @me

Comment: so is any solution to this? -ryantxr

Comment: I think what you observe on screen is not related to what you pass to the ajax. The url reveals 31 just means # as an href points to the  current url. But ajax calling the modal should return record of id 21, right ?

Comment: @KenLee yes, what i want is the modal should return the record of id 21, instead of the id 31,

Comment: Try and fix your HTML first of all. Right now, you are opening a div that you are never closing, according to what you have shown us.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is that you pass data id in view_button and keep your row id in data id.

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary view_btn mb-2" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; 
 ?>" >view</a>
```

then get the data id in jquery-> like this

```
var p_id =  $(this).data('id');
```